# How to not get a black screen when processing c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Whenever I run my code a command prompt window appears and says "process returned 32762 (0x7FFA) execution time .009 seconds press any key to continue." I looked on google and couldnt find a solution.

I expect it to print "hello world"

here is my code

```
// my first C++ program
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The IDE im running is code::blocks

Comment: "process returned 32762 [...]" is an error. I don't use code::blocks, but your code is correct, so it must be a problem with your IDE.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a windows error code. Are you on a different OS?

Comment: Im using windows 10

Comment: Check and see if the executable was created. Also if you are using a different antivirus from the one that comes with the OS temporarily disable it and try again.

Comment: Turning off the firewall didnt help, I dont know if an executable was created or not, what would it be called?

Comment: To be clear, `Hello World!` isn't appearing at all? That is to say, you're not in [a situation like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36237213/10957435) where `Hello World!` appears but you wish to turn off the message after your code executes?

Comment: its not appearing at all

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Also, what happens when you build the program without executing it (_Select "Build" menu ⇒ Build (Ctrl-F9)_)?

Comment: I did not mean the firewall. However from your response you must have the builtin AV.

Comment: I am using the GNU GCC Compiler, when I build the program without executing it it runs through and shows exit code 0 without actually printing "hello world"

Comment: Actually when I build the program it denies me permission to open the executable file

Comment: Try changing it to “Hello, World\n”. Formally, output must be terminated with a newline.

Comment: @PeteBecker Are you sure that applies to C++? I'm only finding things about that for C.

Comment: The only reason you would need `'\n'` would be to flush the output buffer at some intermediate point in your code. However you exit after writing to `cout <<` so exiting would also flush `stdout` (though you really should add the `'\n'` but only so your program doesn't screw up my next prompt on the command line when I test it `:)`

Comment: If you have MinGW installed. Do yourself a favor. Add the path to `where\MinGW\bin` is to your environment. See [How do I add the MinGW bin directory to my system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5733220/3422102) (your user-environment is the TOP box in the dialog) Restart `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) if running. (File->Properties to set font, windows size, and set at least 1000 lines of scrollback). Now just change to the directory where your source file is and do `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o exe_name_you_want your_source.cpp` and run `exe_name_you_want.exe`.  If not MinGW install is bad.

Comment: See [Same Error](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/writing-your-first-program/comment-page-13/#comment-470876) -- which ended up being system language related.

Comment: I have installed MinGW and put it into the path and changed pathext to accept .c files. The error is now that the .exe file doesnt exist (I looked it up in the directory and it isnt there)

Comment: PS ive tried saving the file as a .cpp and I have tried turning off my antivirus software and firewall to no effect.

Comment: I believe that there is something wrong with my path and it has to be reset. Im not actually going to do it though because it requires factory-resetting your computer to an extent and I dont want to deal with it.